# Display words after numbers typed in

Tags: java

I have a test question, where I was asked to write a simple program that reads in 2 integers (i.e one before the decimal point and one after it) and it is meant to display in words whether or not the number should be rounded up or not.

For Example:

```
Enter number between 1 and 5: 3
Enter number between 3 and 6: 5
3.5 was rounded up, it's now four
```

I can get most of it to work except the rounding up part. Please help me.

Below is my code and the output I get

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System. in );
        System.out.print("Enter number between 1 and 5: ");
        int num1 = in .nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter number between 3 and 6: ");
        int num2 = in .nextInt();

        System.out.print(EnglishName(num1, num2));
    }

    public static String EnglishName(int num1, int num2) {

        String numberInWords = "";
        String numberAndDecimal = "";

        if (num1 == 1) {
            numberInWords = "one";
        }
        if (num1 == 2) {
            numberInWords = "two";
        }
        if (num1 == 3) {
            numberInWords = "three";
        }
        if (num1 == 4) {
            numberInWords = "four";
        }
        if (num1 == 5) {
            numberInWords = "five";
        }

        if (num2 == 3) {
            numberAndDecimal = num1 + "." + num2 + " not rounded up its still " + numberInWords;
        }
        if (num2 == 4) {
            numberAndDecimal = num1 + "." + num2 + " not rounded up its still " + numberInWords;
        }
        if (num2 == 5) {
            numberAndDecimal = num1 + "." + num2 + " was rounded up, it's now " + (numberInWords + 1);
        }
        if (num2 == 6) {
            numberAndDecimal = num1 + "." + num2 + " was rounded up, it's now " + (numberInWords + 1);
        }

        return numberAndDecimal;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter number between 1 and 5: 1
Enter number between 3 and 6: 3    
1.3 not rounded up its still one

Enter number between 1 and 5: 3
Enter number between 3 and 6: 5
3.5 was rounded up, it's now three1
```

if I change the lines to

```
if (num2 == 5) {numberAndDecimal = num1 + "." + num2 + " was rounded up, it's now " + (num1 + 1);}
if (num2 == 6) {numberAndDecimal = num1 + "." + num2 + " was rounded up, it's now " + (num1 + 1);}
```

I get this output

```
Enter number between 1 and 5: 3
Enter number between 3 and 6: 5
3.5 was rounded up, it's now 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, first of all: When you do `(numberInWords + 1)` you're adding an int to a String. So Java turns the integer into a string and concatenates them. That's how you get "three1" as an answer.

If you change the lines to

```
if (num2 == 5) {
    numberAndDecimal = num1 + "." + num2 + " was rounded up, it's now " +  (num1 + 1);
}
if (num2 == 6) {
    numberAndDecimal = num1 + "." + num2 + " was rounded up, it's now " + (num1 + 1);
}
```

the output will be 4 when you input 3.5; just not as words.

To translate numbers into words the translation to a string has to happen *after* potentially adding one. So the easiest solution would be to have a separate function which translates ints to Strings. Something like this:

```
public static String EnglishName(int num1, int num2) {

    String numberAndDecimal = "";

    if (num2 == 3) {
        numberAndDecimal = num1 + "." + num2 + " not rounded up its still "
                + translate(num1);
    }
    if (num2 == 4) {
        numberAndDecimal = num1 + "." + num2 + " not rounded up its still "
                + translate(num1);
    }
    if (num2 == 5) {
        numberAndDecimal = num1 + "." + num2 + " was rounded up, it's now "
                + translate(num1 + 1);
    }
    if (num2 == 6) {
        numberAndDecimal = num1 + "." + num2 + " was rounded up, it's now "
                + translate(num1 + 1);
    }

    return numberAndDecimal;
}

public static String translate(int num1) {

    String numberInWords = "";

    if (num1 == 1) {
        numberInWords = "one";
    }
    if (num1 == 2) {
        numberInWords = "two";
    }
    if (num1 == 3) {
        numberInWords = "three";
    }
    if (num1 == 4) {
        numberInWords = "four";
    }
    if (num1 == 5) {
        numberInWords = "five";
    }

    return numberInWords;
}
```

PS.: Please keep to Java coding conventions by naming your functions with names starting with lowercase letters. So in your case it should be something like `englishName` rather than `EnglishName`.

Comment: You're welcome. There are by the way other things that could be improved in your program; for example, I'd recommend using `else` in addition to `if` and maybe using `<` and `>=` for comparison rather than `==` in some places.

Comment: That worked perfect thanks. I now have to figure it out how to get it to returns the appropriate error messages when the user enter a wrong integer or else a letter.

Comment: while (!in.hasNextInt())
{
System.out.println("Invalid entry, please try again ");
in.next();
}

Comment: That line above will help me if the user enters a letter but how do I also include if a user enters an invalid number?

Comment: You could have a function `boolean checkNumber(int input)` which would test the number which was entered. All together it would look something like this: `while(true) {if(!in.hasNextInt()) {System.out.println("Invalid entry, please try again"); continue;} else {int input = in.next(); if(!checkNumber(input)) {System.out.println("The number you entered is invalid, please try again");} else { break; }}}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
String num = num1 + "." + num2;
double number = Double.parseDouble(num);
int roundOffAns = (int)Math.round(number);
```

Comment: In any real scenario this would be a good idea, yes. It doesn't however solve the problem which lies in the order of execution and the concatenation of Strings.

Comment: you are right.My point was to tell her an optimized solution or an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

When i ran the code with the correct fix at the bottom:

```
if (num2 == 5) {numberAndDecimal = num1 + "." + num2 + " was rounded up, it's now " + (num1 + 1);}
if (num2 == 6) {numberAndDecimal = num1 + "." + num2 + " was rounded up, it's now " + (num1 + 1);}
```

Enter number between 1 and 5: 3
Enter number between 3 and 6: 5
3.5 was rounded up, it's now 4

Comment: Yeah, but it's meant to write the word four not the number 4